# How to display website in iframe using jQuery code from anyorigin.com/alloworigin.com/whateverorigin.com

Tags: jquery, iframe

While searching for ways to get over cross-domain policy I came across sites like alloworigin.com and anyorigin.com they all gave jquery code like this

```
 $.getJSON("http://alloworigin.com/get?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://google.com") + "&callback=?", function(data){
          alert(data.contents);
      });
```

`alloworigin.com` shows the content of the webpage inside an `iframe` 
similarly now I need to display the google page on a basic html page in an iframe inside any div id so how should I do that 
and if we had jquery code for other websites too so can we display more then one website in iframes in the same page
can anyone give the sample very basic html code for displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## html

```
<iframe id="json" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>
```

## javascript

```
var url = 'http://cnn.com'
url = "http://alloworigin.com/get?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    
    var d = $("#json")[0].contentWindow.document; // contentWindow works in IE7 and FF
    d.open(); d.close(); // must open and close document object to start using it!
    
    // now start doing normal jQuery:
    $("body", d).append(data.contents);
});
```

**include jquery**